# Can reprepro accept a new version of a package into the repository?

Tags: linux, debian, apt, deb

I have installed a package into my own debian package repository like so:

```
$ sudo reprepro -b /var/packages/ubuntu includedeb maverick my-package_0.8-0_all.deb 
my-package_0.8-0_all.deb: component guessed as 'main'
Exporting indices...
```

I have installed my package on a few machines using apt-get install.

I have now added new features to my software and would like to add a new minor version of my package to the repository so that I may update my machines using apt-get upgrade.

I try to do this like so:

```
$ sudo reprepro -b /var/packages/ubuntu includedeb maverick my-package_0.9-0_all.deb 
my-package_0.9-0_all.deb: component guessed as 'main'
Skipping inclusion of 'my-package' '1.0-0' in 'maverick|main|i386', as it has already '1.0-0'.
Skipping inclusion of 'my-package' '1.0-0' in 'maverick|main|amd64', as it has already '1.0-0'.
```

It looks like I need to tell reprepro that this is a new version of the same package but I have no idea how to do this. I have read the reprepro man page several times and searched on the net for a couple of hours but I have not found any answers.

Am I missing something?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reprepro is not able to hold two versions of a package in the same distribution.

See answer to question 3.1 here: https://web.archive.org/web/20120103201823/http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=mirrorer/reprepro.git;a=blob_plain;f=docs/FAQ;hb=HEAD

Comment: If this is your answer, you should mark it accepted. and welcome to serverfault :)

Comment: Dead link as of 11/15/13.

Comment: Link is still dead.

Comment: Archived version of the Link: https://web.archive.org/web/20120103201823/http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=mirrorer/reprepro.git;a=blob_plain;f=docs/FAQ;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 4):

When you build your dpkg, you should increment the package version as per [here](http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-pkgname).

The Debian Revision Number (the -xxx at the end of packages) is the one you should increment.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but changing the number at the end of the package did not help my problem. I tried first adding a package my-package_1.0-0_all.deb and then my-package_1.0-1_all.deb but got exactly the same error as above saying that it already has 1.0-0.

Comment: Dropping the _all also made no difference.

Comment: what's the "skipping inclusion" line when you try to add your new package version?

Comment: The skipping inclusion line is where reprepro is trying to add my-package_0.9-0_all.deb as version 1.0-0 and finding that it is already in the repository. I would really like to be able to tell reprepro that this is a new version of an existing package! That is my problem.

Comment: When you say "Changing the number at the end", do you mean changing the file name or editing the version number in the control file?

Comment: I meant the specific text you saw, but it sounds like you solved your problem on your own ;)